# How to arrange the item position in ngFor

Tags: angular

positionDetails: [
            {
                position: 20,
                positionType: "ABC"
            },
            {
                position: 1000,
                positionType: "XYZ"
            }]

```
        <div *ngFor="let pos of element.positionDetails" [ngSwitch]="pos.positionType">

        <span *ngSwitchCase="'XYZ'"> {{pos?.position }} {{pos?.positionType}}</span>

        <span *ngSwitchCase="'ABC'">{{pos?.position }} {{pos?.positionType}}  </span>

        </div>
```

expected result: 1000 XYZ 20 ABC

Comment: Switch one is the specific error?

Comment: are you trying to have the items displayed based on the position number? if so, this shouldn't be handled in the template, you should sort your array in the Class. and let the template simply simply display the result. i.e. `element.positionDetails = element.positionDetails.sort(....);`

Comment: You need to sort your record before using it or use pipe for that, see this http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example

Answer (score 1):

Try with a nested `span` for the `ngSwitch` like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let pos of element.positionDetails">
    <span [ngSwitch]="pos.positionType">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'XYZ'" class="base-points"> {{ pos?.position }} {{ pos?.positionType }} </span>
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'ABC'"> {{ pos?.position }} {{pos?.positionType }} / </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

stackblitz DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2mqnc

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly rearrange elements in the ***ngFor***. This is because ***ngFor*** is used for parsing the array, not to modify them.

If you want to rearrange them, then there are two methods.

1. Pass the array to the ***ngFor*** as you desired.
2. Use Sort methods to sort your array based on any condition.

Check the [implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwwph7)